# iOS - OpenURL from Keyboard extension on iOS 8.3 beta

Tags: ios8, deep-linking, ios8-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

On my project I used a WebView to open a Container App from Keyboard extension.
It worked ok until I tried to run it on iOS 8.3 beta.. On this new iOS version it just do **nothing**.

I tried to use *NSExtensionContext* and *WKWebView* - without any success too.

Does someone know how to openURL on keyboard extension on iOS8.3?

Thanks

Comment: `WKWebView` doesn't have a method like `[NSExtensionContext openURL:]`. What did you try with it, and what happened when you did?

Comment: @TomHarrington it has a `- loadRequest:` method. It works before 8.3

Comment: Did you manage to achieve any progress with this? Just updated to iOS 8.3 yesterday and I'm experiencing the same problem....

Comment: @orenk86 nope, I didn't find any workaround for this

Answer (score 5):

Can you try this snippet?

```
-(void)openURL:(NSString*)url{
    UIResponder* responder = self;
    while ((responder = [responder nextResponder]) != nil) {
        NSLog(@"responder = %@", responder);
        if ([responder respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:)] == YES) {
            [responder performSelector:@selector(openURL:)
                            withObject:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        }
    }
}
```

Cited from 
http://yusukekuni.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/05/01/144050

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a custom action.

As far as i know, using a webview to openUrl in an extension is a workaround and is not supported officially by the sdk. It seems that Apple removed it completely in iOS 8.3.

The only extension that supports openUrl for now is the widget.